# How to choose the default database on odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am using odoo 11 enterprise edition and I use two databases. Each time a visitor uses our website he can choose to use any database

Is there any method to choose the default database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `db_name = your database name` to config file.
or,
You can add `-d your_database_name` to your command which starts up odoo server.

When multiple database available, you can limit database list to certain regex expression using `db_filter` in config file.

For more detailed information, follow the official documentation [Odoo deployment](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html).